PostgreSQL database not connecting to spring-boot application
I am currently setting up postgreSQL db for my spring-boot project. However, when I try to launch the tomcat server I get exception saying that the repository beans could not be created due to this:
Caused by: jakarta.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution [FATAL: password authentication failed for user "dev-user"] [n/a]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:421) ~[spring-orm-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:366) ~[spring-orm-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1853) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1802) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    ... 101 common frames omitted

In my properties.yml I have this:
spring:
 datasource:
   url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/authentication_db
   username: dev-user
   password: password
   driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
 jpa:
   hibernate:
     ddl-auto: update
   show-sql: false
   properties:
     hibernate:
       format_sql: true
   database: postgresql
   database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect

In my docker-compose.yml I have this:
services:
 postgres:
   container_name: postgres-sql-pa
   image: postgres
   environment:
     POSTGRES_USER: dev-user
     POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
     PGDATA: /var/lib/postgresql/data
     POSTGRES_DB: authentication_db
   volumes:
     - postgres:/data/postgres
   ports:
     - 5432:5432
   networks:
     - spring-demo
   restart: unless-stopped

Why am I having this exception? I can see that docker container is running fine and the info on the db tells me that the properties db_name, username, password are set correctly

Pretty obvious FATAL: password authentication failed for user "dev-user"]. Use the correct password.

I am already using it, I even set up the password in the db as "password" to double check but I still cant connect

could it be that you already have postgres installed and running as a program next to the container? check by using a different port for docker container (e.g. 5433) and try connecting to that

I have replaced the 5432:5432 to 5433:5433 but docker still shows that db is running in 5432, Is there another place I need to change it?

no docker should still run in 5432, you should just map it to 5433 on your host (done with - 5433:5432 in your docker-compose.yml). Also dont forget to update url in properties to url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5433/authentication_db

Do you have any documentation or example on how to do this?

updated my comment

To your question add the following information: 1) Postgres version. 2) Relevant information from the Postgres log regarding the connection attempt. 3) The relevant portion of pg_hba.conf. 4) Did you migrate data from another database into this one?

Hello, the fix was actually provided from @JAsgarov, I did what he mentioned and is now working

The fix that worked for me was based on @JAsgarov comment. Basicalle changing from 5432:5432 to 5433:5432 and updating the URL

just to clarify, not a fix, simply a workaround to the fact that on your computer the port 5432 is already taken by some other application (most likely postgres either installed as a program or running in a different container). Glad it helped

Yeh Thanks a lot for all the help you have been giving also in other posts!
